# how to force netwtonsoft json serializer to serialize datetime property to string?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft's Json
when i serialze a date time property i get the json response as:

```
..."CreatedOn":"\/Date(1317303882420+0500)\/",...
```

i want it to be in simple string as

```
..."createdOn": "2011-05-05 14:03:07", ...
```

while my class property is DateTime, how can i force to serialze it as string, as we can add attribute to change the property name as

```
  [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
```

is there a similar way to force a DateTime property to serialize to string??

Comment: Please provide the JSON object that you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: Please note that as of Json.NET 4.5 Dates are written using the ISO 8601 format by default http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm (ISO 8601 formatted string: "2009-02-15T00:00:00Z")

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From a post made by James Newton-King on StackOverflow, it looks like you can do this.

```
string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
// {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}
```

Referenced answer:
[Parsing JSON DateTime from Newtonsoft's JSON Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668488/parsing-json-datetime-from-newtonsofts-json-serializer)

Also here is the documentation on Json.NET and dates:
[Serializing Dates in JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm)

Here is an example of using the `DateTimeFormat` property to customize the output:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" });
```

Comment: thanx for the response ...
this is cool it works.. but infact i need the date time to be as
"LogDate":"2009-02-15 00:00:00"
not T in between date and time

Comment: Have a look at the documentation in the last link in the post.  It says something about: "The IsoDateTimeConverter class has a property, DateTimeFormat, to further customize the formatted string."  Try fiddling with that.

Comment: is there a way to decorate my MVC model class property so Newtonsoft.Json will utilize a preferred DateTime format? Or can a converter be specified at a global level so that my whole WebApi stable of controllers serialize all models with Date properties using a desired date format?

Comment: ok. figured it out just now: WebApiConfig.Register method, added this line:         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Shouldn't that be `HH:mm:ss` on the second example?

Comment: Yes it should be HH because there is no tt to indicate AM or PM.  I tried to edit to fix it but there is a BS rule that only edits of six characters or more are accepted so I didn't waste my time trying to think of 4 more characters to edit.

Comment: And for this `2018-02-06T14:40:43.511Z` ?

Comment: `settings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ" });`