# Json Datetime issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to force netwtonsoft json serializer to serialize datetime property to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670629/how-to-force-netwtonsoft-json-serializer-to-serialize-datetime-property-to-strin)

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to convert my object in to JSON file.
But I am having issue with the `DateTime`, in my object datetime field is set as `"7/30/2012 8:29:12 PM"` but in JSON file. I am getting `DateTime` field in this format:

`"\/Date(1343660352227+0530)\/"`.

I need to get the `DateTime` in the same format as that of the object.                                                                                                                                                                                        Is it possible? What should I do in order to get the same format?

Comment: You are not the only one with that problem, see 
[Scott Hanselman - On the nightmare that is JSON Dates. Plus, JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply,i will check the links...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the solution as follow.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new IsoDateTimeConverter() {
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
});
```

Here is the answer:

[how to force netwtonsoft json serializer to serialize datetime property to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670629/how-to-force-netwtonsoft-json-serializer-to-serialize-datetime-property-to-strin)