# Json Format Date

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I encounter a problem where I could not get the  new Date()  because the  date it's in JSON format. This code is done using MVC C#.
The  date is in  `\/Date(1531364413000)\/`.
The date in the database is in yy-mm-dd
Can I change the format in the controller or in the web config?
Anybody knows how do I change the default date into JavaScript format?

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820896/convert-datetime-to-json-datetime or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757757/json-datetime-issue ?

Comment: There is no "JSON format". You can specify a pattern or format in your schema to validate against though.

Comment: nope. I want to make the Javascript date format default. I'm using Model-View-Controller

Comment: What do you consider the "date format default"?

Comment: so that it will be able to change it automatically without adding  a class to it

Comment: What do you call "JavaScript format"? The value can be converted to an ECMAScript date usng `new Date(1531364413000)`, though you must ensure you convert it to number first. You can use various methods to extract the time value from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper javascript function like this

```
function (date) {
     if (!date)
          return "";
     var dtStart = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
     var dtStartWrapper = moment(dtStart);
     return dtStartWrapper.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

It uses Moment Js