# Serialize DateTime property IsoDateTimeConverter and ServerProtocolViolation Error

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net

I have this classes:

```
    public class EncuestaRespuesta
    {
        public string idCaso { get; set; }
        public string tipoEncuesta { get; set; }
        public string codMovimiento { get; set; }
        public string motivoRetirada { get; set; }
        public string duracion { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaHora { get; set; }
        public string gestor { get; set; }
        public List<RespuestasEncuesta> listRespuestasEncuestas { get; set;}
    }

    public class RespuestasEncuesta
    {
        public string pregunta { get; set; }
        public string respuesta { get; set; }
        public string numOrdenTrabajo { get; set; }
    }
```

Using JSON.NET,

```
    // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };

    settings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()); 

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

When I call REST API (`HttpClient PostAsync`), I get the error:

> "The server committed a protocol violation.
>   Section=ResponseStatusLine"  Error: ServerProtocolViolation

I don't why. My JSON string:

```
 {
  "idCaso": "5009E000007Hp94QAD",
  "codMovimiento": "1",
  "motivoRetirada": "2",
  "duracion": "0",
  "fechaHora": "2018-03-20T12:56:36.4841861Z",
  "gestor": "GESTOR SALESFORCE",
  "tipoEncuesta": "T3_1018_RM",
  "listRespuestasEncuestas": [
    {
      "numOrdenTrabajo": "",
      "pregunta": "",
      "respuesta": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like this JSON string, is OK in my tests:

```
{
  "idCaso": "5009E000007Hp94QAC",
  "codMovimiento": "1",
  "motivoRetirada": "1",
  "duracion": "",
  "fechaHora": "2018-02-06T14:40:43.511Z",
  "gestor": "",
  "tipoEncuesta": "T3_1018_RM",
  "listRespuestasEncuestas": [
    {
      "numOrdenTrabajo": "",
      "pregunta": "",
      "respuesta": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**Issue:** The dateTime field:

```
"fechaHora": "2018-03-20T12:56:36.4841861Z",
```

is **wrong**

```
"fechaHora": "2018-02-06T14:40:43.511Z"
```

is **OK**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I use `IsoDateTimeConverter` with `DateTimeFormat`:

```
// https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

settings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ" });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

**Dates JSON**

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

[how to force netwtonsoft json serializer to serialize datetime property to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670629/how-to-force-netwtonsoft-json-serializer-to-serialize-datetime-property-to-strin)

[Serializing multiple DateTime properties in the same class using different formats for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856580/serializing-multiple-datetime-properties-in-the-same-class-using-different-forma)

[Newtonsoft.json IsoDateTimeConverter and DateFormatHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138659/newtonsoft-json-isodatetimeconverter-and-dateformathandling)

**DateTime Format UTC**

[How can I format DateTime to web UTC format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820915/how-can-i-format-datetime-to-web-utc-format)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings