# Deserialize JSON DateTime with time zone

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I'm doing this for two hours and nothing. This is the date in JSON:

```
"\/Date(1330355834000+0100)\/"
```

Everything I found was without timezone or for JavaScript. How to convert it to DateTime (not Date)?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668488/parsing-json-datetime-from-newtonsofts-json-serializer

Comment: Have you tried Json.Net? it deserializes it to correct DateTime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman just posted an article about the pains of this. [His post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a json date and time with timezone using something like this:

```
var publishDate = new Date().toJSON();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) that can parse the data ad you would like. This gives you complete control over how your objects transform in to JSON objects and vice versa.