# Parse "\/Date(1427565325073+0100)\/" to DateTime in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, .net-2.0

There are lots of examples of how to parse a "json date" in C# using .net4+, But I havent found many which will work on .Net 2.0.

Like this one [Parsing JSON DateTime from Newtonsoft's JSON Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668488/parsing-json-datetime-from-newtonsofts-json-serializer) which works great if you have .net4 and can use libraries..

I however only have base .Net 2 at my disposal.

So, what is the best way to parse this:

> "/Date(1427565325073+0100)/"

To a C# `System.DateTime`.

My code current code does not work with timezones.

```
private System.DateTime ParseJsonDate(string jsondate)
{
    jsondate = jsondate.Replace("/Date(", "");
    jsondate = jsondate.Replace(")/", string.Empty);  
    var expDate = new System.DateTime(long.Parse(jsondate));

    return expDate;
}
```

Comment: Try this URL: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can try to find early versions of JSON.NET, I believe there are some that support .NET 2.0.

If you can't find any, you can to through [JSON.NET source code on github](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) and find the code, which does the job and proved by the time and people.

Or you can write your own implementation based on my small sample:

```
var input = "/Date(1427565325073+0100)/";

var dateVal = input.Substring(6, input.Length - 8);
Console.WriteLine(dateVal);

var parts = dateVal.Split('+');
var milliseconds = long.Parse(parts[0]);
var utcTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
Console.WriteLine(utcTime);

var localTime = utcTime;
if (parts.Length > 1)
{
    var hoursMinutes = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    localTime = localTime.AddHours(hoursMinutes / 100).AddMinutes(hoursMinutes % 100);
}
Console.WriteLine(localTime);
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm), Json.NET "Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, .NET 4.5, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8 Store".  So OP should be able to use the current version.

Comment: @dbc great! so the problem should go away